# Joomla Session Issue

Tags: php, session, joomla

There are two joomla site under same domain

http://example.com/en/ - English site

http://example.com/ch/ - Chinese site

Here the problem is if the user login in the English site and if he open the Chinese site then user appears logged in even if the user was not register in the Chinese site and products in the cart were also appearing in the Chinese site

how can we prevent user session  accessing other site sessions

Thanks
Murali

Comment: Do you use the same database for both sites? If yes there is no way to differentiate between the two sessions

Comment: actually there is a way to differentiate, if you set the path of the session cookies to /en and /ch, but I have never done it in Joomla. If you find out how please share your research.